# Possible to ignore a .where method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a page where I user's posts are displayed:

`user.posts`

I want to add the functionality to only show a user's posts of a certain category:

`user.posts.where(category_id: category_id_variable)`

To avoid duplication of code I wonder if it's possible to keep the code line above for *both* scenarios, i.e. somehow ignore the `.where` method if I want to display all the user's posts?

Comment: If you only want to do the `user.posts` once, then you could do `user_posts = user.posts` for all cases, then, under the constraining condition, do `user_posts = user_posts.where(category_id: category_id_variable)`. You really can't just ignore the `where`. With Rails lazy loading, `user.posts` is not an expensive statement.

Comment: Where is the duplication of code?

Comment: @PNY I'm aware now that the question is badly written. This is a (very) simplified query of what I have, and that's why I (visually) would be pleased to save a 3 lines if I don't need to write the query twice.

Comment: @Numbers I really don't understand where the duplication is. The above perform completely different queries. Do not DRY the above in that context. DRY applies to concepts not lines of code.

Comment: You're right. Would like to delete the question, but not possible now that it has answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your controller's action:

```
posts = user.posts 
@posts = posts.where(category_id: category_id_variable).all if category_id_variable.present?
@posts = posts.all unless category_id_variable.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `unscope`. In your example code, you would do `user.posts.where(category_id: category_variable).except(:where)` to get the same results as `user.posts`.

See [ActiveRecord query guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#unscope) for details.